What is the source of the Indrakshi Stotra
Does anyone know the source of this beautiful Indrakshi Stotra?
The most information I've been able to find is:

Sage Narada during one of his visits to Vaikunta asked Lord Narayana
for the reason why whiles Devas and Asuras are healthy by nature,
human beings suffer these numerous diseases. Then lord Narayana taught
him the Indrakshi sthothra. He told Narada that by reciting this
Sthothra, one can lead a disease free happy life. Sage narada taught
it to Indra, who in turn taught it to Sage Purandara. It was Sage
Purandara who popularized it among human beings.

